# Magento 2 Order API, updating order status

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to update the order status via the orders/{id}/comments API.

I'm doing it via Python for now and I keep getting an error.

```
putURL = "https://myStore.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/286660/comments"
data = [{"statusHistory":{"entity_id" : "286660" , "status" : "Backordered"}}]
response = requests.post(putURL , json=data, headers=headers)
```

I'm getting:

```
       {"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"statusHistory"}}
```

Isn't this the bare minimum that the API requires? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning.

you should follow this structure in your request. the parent_id is the orderId you are trying to add the comment to.

```
{
    "statusHistory": 
    {
        "is_customer_notified": 1,
        "parent_id": 474,
        "status": "processing",
        "comment": "Test webservice",
        "is_visible_on_front": 1
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any furthe assistance and don't forget to upvote/mark as answer if this solver your issue.

Comment: Thank you, the correct formatting worked. But now, I have a new problem, the status just blanks out.

Comment: Adding a comment does not change the order status. Could you update the OP with the code you are using so I can have a look? Also make sure the status you are using exists within the order state. Go to your admin and STORES => Order Status